# How to retrieve data stored in select2 dropdown?

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, jquery-select2

I am using `laravel` 5 and `select2` dropdown for selecting various tags similar to stackoverflow tag field.

So once a number of tags are selected i want to retrieve them in the form of array and use it in laravel 5's controller to validate and store.

Also if user clicks edit post i want to add all the tags in the dropdown from the `database` so user can easily make changes.

1) So mainly i want to know how can i retrieve data in form of array from `select2`

2) populate the `select2` with data when user clicks edit
How do i achieve these 2 functionality ?

```
<select multiple="multiple"
    id="tag_select"
    class="form-control{{ $errors->has('tag_select') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
    name="tag_select"
    value="{{ old('tag_select') }}"
    required
    >

    <option value="">PHP</option>
    <option value="">C++</option>
</select>

<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        $("#tag_select").select2();

        $('#show_select').click(function(){
            $("#tag_select").text();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Add the code which you have related  to this so that it can be more easier to help.

Comment: please add some of your code here first then ask for the help.

Comment: added code please check now

Comment: Time to retract your down vote! [at]AnkitAgarwal @DhavalPurohit

Comment: @Raj no need to retrieve from `select2` you already have it in your `html`

Comment: @Mr.x so when i submit the form would i get an array of selected item when i reference the select dropdown on the server side ?

Comment: @Raj yes, stay tune, I making a snippet for you.

Comment: yes you will get the array in your controller. if you are using multiple select then the name should be given as array  for ex. `tag_select[]`

Comment: I think this is the only thing that you have forgotten to add to your HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get selected `tags` by `select2:select` event:

```js
$("#class_select").select2();

var tagsArray = new Array();

$('#class_select').on('select2:select', function(e) {
  var text = e.params.data.text; // get text
  var id = e.params.data.id; // get value

  tagsArray.push(text);
  console.log(tagsArray);
});
```

```css
select#class_select {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>

<select multiple="multiple" id="class_select" class="form-control" name="tag_select" required>
    <option value="1">PHP</option>
    <option value="2">C++</option>
</select>
```

Also you can get selected by native `html`:

```js
$("#class_select").select2();

var tagsArray = new Array();

$('#class_select').on('change', function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  tagsArray.push(val);
  console.log(tagsArray);
});
```

```css
select#class_select {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>

<select multiple="multiple" id="class_select" class="form-control" name="tag_select[]" required>
    <option value="1">PHP</option>
    <option value="2">C++</option>
</select>
```

Comment: just one more question, when i submit the form how do i get access to the tagsArray in laravel controller ?

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not a `laravel` expert, but in `php` you can get a `js` array with `json` or `ajax` @Raj But you can search about: `How to get jquery array in laravel`